# How to verify if $_GET exists?

Tags: php, html, urlvariables

So, I have some PHP code that looks a bit like this:

```
<body>
    The ID is 

    <?php
    echo $_GET["id"] . "!";
    ?>

</body>
```

Now, when I pass an ID like `http://localhost/myphp.php?id=26` it works alright, but if there is no ID like just `http://localhost/myphp.php` then it outputs:

```
The ID is
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\myphp.php on line 9
!
```

I have searched for a way to fix this but I cannot find any way to check if a URL variable exists. I know there must be a way though.

Comment: Undefined index is not an error, it is just a warning. You can turn off warning by editing the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: verifying if `$_GET` exists (like in the subject) is actually another question, you're trying to verify if `$_GET["id"]` exists...

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use `isset` function:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // id index exists
}
```

You can create a handy function to return default value if index doesn't exist:

```
function Get($index, $defaultValue) {
    return isset($_GET[$index]) ? $_GET[$index] : $defaultValue;
}

// prints "invalid id" if $_GET['id'] is not set
echo Get('id', 'invalid id');
```

You can also try to validate it at the same time:

```
function GetInt($index, $defaultValue) {
    return isset($_GET[$index]) && ctype_digit($_GET[$index])
            ? (int)$_GET[$index] 
            : $defaultValue;
}

// prints 0 if $_GET['id'] is not set or is not numeric
echo GetInt('id', 0);
```

Answer (score 19):

```
   if (isset($_GET["id"])){
        //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) built-in function:

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {
    echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

or the [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) built-in function:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to using one over the other? array_key_exists seems more right, but I've almost always used isset.

Answer (score 9):

Normally it is quite good to do:

```
echo isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'wtf';
```

This is so when assigning the var to other variables you can do defaults all in one breath instead of constantly using `if` statements to just give them a default value if they are not set.

Comment: WTF is an example...plus it is `wtf` not `wft`

Comment: Better options would be `null` or `0`.

Comment: @Asaph `wtf` is the new `null` :P though he was also echoing and as the OP said themselves they replaced `wtf` with `No ID!` and that's really what it was designed for, ehcoing `null` isn't very useful, in this case `wtf` was more useful than `null` imo

Comment: @Asaph Also 0 could be a valid ID so that's not such a good response for it not being set either.

Comment: `wtf` is an awsome value.

Answer (score 6):

You are use PHP [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Example

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo $_GET["id"];
}
```

Comment: yeah .. but do to the documentation for more examples

Answer (score 5):

Use and `empty()` whit negation (for test if not empty)

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    // if get id is not empty
}
```

Comment: What if the id is 0? Remember empty returns false for numerous things.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
   echo $_GET["id"];
 }
```

Comment: `empty($_GET['id'])` is translated to `!isset($var) || $var == false.`, so the `isset($_GET['id'])` is not required.