# How to check which GET request is passed on?

Tags: php, validation, get

Like the title says, how do I determine which GET value has been passed on within the url?

Take `http://www.example.com/view.php?id=20`as an example. The current GET value is 'id', with a value of 20. This works great, but if someone plays around and changes the GET value to something other than 'id', I get a lot of PHP errors on the page.

So my goal is to check wether the passed GET value is incorrect, so I can redirect them to another page. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['id']))`

Comment: That's exactly what I had, but it would still give an error because I had the query for searching the id in the database outside of that if statement, so whenever a different get request was passed on, it couldn't find the $_GET['id']. Changed it now, thanks!

Comment: Well, what about putting the condition before the query?

Comment: @Waqas that is not same with this one however it is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019684/how-to-verify-if-get-exists

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the URL parameters. In your case, it has to be `id` and that has to be `numeric`:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
```

As an advance check, you can validate whether `id` is integer or not:

```
if((int)$_GET['id'] == $_GET['id']){
    return TRUE;            
} else {        
    return FALSE; // It's a number, but not an integer
}
```