# How can I judge a variable whether is assign in Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty project. in the php file I will assign the variable `bar` dynamically.

in the php file's corresponding template:

```
{if $bar}{$bar}{/if}
```

but I will get bellow error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: bar in /Users/sof/Desktop/TestIOS/smarty-test02/templates_c/6f98597c1882f0124e0891c8343f1404eff83e24_0.file.test.tpl.cache.php on line 63

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/sof/Desktop/TestIOS/smarty-test02/templates_c/6f98597c1882f0124e0891c8343f1404eff83e24_0.file.test.tpl.cache.php on line 63
```

How can I judge a variable whether is assign?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify if $\_GET exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019684/how-to-verify-if-get-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

```
{if isset($bar)}{$bar}{/if}
```

Comment: But this is in smarty template, does this is use PHP's isset? or the smarty template grammar's isset?

Comment: Try it and you will know. It uses PHP's isset.